# Deploy Python apps to Azure App Service on Windows Server

Tags: django, azure, windows-server-2012-r2

I can't find any proper guideline how to deploy a Django web application on Windows Server, almost all tutorials talk about Linux. Can someone explain or give a link?

I now we need an IIS. What about DNS and AD, or any other services? I would like to know the relationship among IIS, DNS and AD, or any other services.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to deploy a Python app to Windows app service is to use the [Devops Projects](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/devops-projects/)

Step 1: Create a Python Project

Step 2: Choose an application framework as Django

Step 3: Select the Windows Web App

Step 4: Fill the rest of the settings.

Once the project is created you can pass the custom code and do the deployment from the Azure Devops pipelines.

EDIT

if you want to deploy the app on VM follow the steps as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@ayushi21095/steps-to-deploy-python-django-web-application-on-windows-iis-server-379b2b87fcf9).

Comment: Thanks, what about windows server IIS AD and DNS?

Comment: why do you need IIS AD, DNS can be configured

Comment: How can you deploy an app without IIS on Windows?

Comment: yeah you can, thats what https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/ is for.

Comment: No you cant, you need a VM and there is a windows server, you have to connect it to Azure then IIS. Your link is a general link.

Comment: you want to deploy on a VM?

Comment: I have a VM and windows server 2012 R2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205192/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-nessi).